# Restarting SSRS using SQL Agent & Powershell

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, powershell, ssrs-2012

I'd like to create a SQL agent job to restart SSRS each day.

In the past i've used a Powershell script executed by a Scheduled task [taken from here](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/07/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/). This has worked fine, but I would prefer it to be a single job in SQL agent to simplify deployment and admin maintenance.

I have taken the powershell code and added a job with a single step.

```
Stop-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
Start-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
$wc = New-Object system.net.webClient
$cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$wc.Credentials = $cred
$src = $wc.DownloadString("http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx")
```

When I run it I get the following error.

```
The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:
A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Stop-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Service 'SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) (ReportServer)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open ReportServer service on computer '.'.
Cannot open ReportServer service on computer '.'.
Access is denied.
```

And a similar error for the start service command.

My SQL agent is running with local admin privileges. So I assume is has sufficient privs to do this.

What am I missing? Is there some technical limitation in SQL Agent stopping this from working?

Comment: What happens if you create a .ps1 file and use a command line job step calling powershell.exe &'yourscript.ps1'? SQL Agent powershell steps are notoriously limited. There's also the chance you might need to use an elevated powershell session to do this, but try calling out using the command line first.

Comment: Apologies for delay in replying. Ive been busy with other issues. I believe my problem is security/elevation related. Ill have another go in Monday and post what I find.

Comment: Did you look into proxy accounts for agent jobs?

Comment: Sorry I havent has a chance to get back to this. This was a low priority side project.

Comment: I'm hoping you have a solution for this. I also need to find a way to restart the SSRS services on a number of systems.

Comment: Restarting ssrs isnt the only issue. The delay after restarting is caused by the reloading of the appdomain. You need something that works like a browser to open an ssrs url to make it come to life.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy see reply above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11207049/4700939